# Launch Company Specific apps on iTunes App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

We have an app to launch on App Store. This App is for a company users(free to download) not for publicly use. Our client has purchased the iOS developer program instead of Enterprise account. So is there any way to launch the App on AppStore using developer program. (like Custom B2B).

Please suggest your ideas. So I can proceed to right way.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A company-specific app is not appropriate for the app store; other people could download it. The company needs to purchase an Enterprise Licence and setup some device management.

Comment: @RoboticCat: Can't I distribute my app using Custom B2B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do so. If you are thinking of Custom B2B, you must know that:-

The Volume Purchase Program is available in:
Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, New Zealand, Spain, United Kingdom, and the United States.

If you or your client belong to these of the countries then you can use it otherwise you have to get an Enterprise account to do so.